# Why does AWS use { "Key" : key, "Value" : val} syntax?

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3

I am used (in Python and Java) to seeing dicts/hashmaps defined as { key : value}

AWS uses the format { "Key" : key, "Value" : val }

Where does this approach come from?  It adds complexity, is there a benefit to be gained from that complexity?

EDIT: an example is the format for [tags](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.create_tags):

```
Tags=[
    {
        'Key': 'string',
        'Value': 'string'
    },
]
```

Comment: Can you post links to where have you seen this?

Comment: The AWS ecosystem allows you to create custom attributes in some places, which means that their key naming needs to be flexible. This effect trickles down to boto output.  It's way less annoying than not being able to properly tag your resources.

Comment: @ingernet, can you give an example of how this format would allow you to create a custom attribute, when the { K : V } syntax wouldn't?

Comment: This implements a more extendible schema: if one day they decide to add another attribute it would be possible. Eg: `RemoveAfter` property for tags to be automatically removed after the date. It would be impossible with `key: value` approach.

Comment: @zerkms what does {'Key' : k, 'Value' : v, 'RemoveAfter' : <date>} have that { k : v, 'RemoveAfter' : <date>} doesn't?

Comment: @weegolo how do you specify different `RemoveAfter` for every key? Or only have it for one key? Do you also realise that in your suggestion you cannot have a custom key named `RemoveAfter` anymore?

Comment: @zerkms Tags = [ { k1 : v1, RemoveAfter = <date>}, { k2 : v2, RemoveAfter = <date> }].  Yes, I suppose the current format does allow you to have a tag { "Key" : 'RemoveAfter', "Value" : <date>, "RemoveAfter" : <otherdate> }, but that seems a confusing programming style

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility: AWS tends to use the same formats for data structures on the wire for different cases, for consistency, reducing overall system complexity by reducing variability.  Blatant examples of this are S3 event notifications and Lambda@Edge triggers, where the event data structure (shown here as `{ ... }`) is unnecessarily wrapped in an outer object with one key and an inner array with one member as `{"Records": [{ ... }]}` even though by definition in these cases the `Records` array can never have more or less than one inner object.  They do this for consistency.

Another possible explanation: the low-level APIs that the SDK is using to communicate with the service use XML¹, where this structure makes more sense.

From the EC2 API Reference, [`DescribeTags` action](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/API_DescribeTags.html), here's a sample response:

```xml
<tagSet>
  <item>
     <resourceId>ami-1a2b3c4d</resourceId>
     <resourceType>image</resourceType>
     <key>webserver</key>
     <value/>
  </item>
  <item>
     <resourceId>ami-1a2b3c4d</resourceId>
     <resourceType>image</resourceType>
     <key>stack</key>
     <value>Production</value>
  </item>
  ...
</tagSet>
```

It's an array of objects with multiple attributes.  That isn't always the case, but this takes us back to the "consistency" argument, above.

It's admittedly often very awkward to work with, and a dictionary would seem much more straightforward, but the SDKs appear to be simply preserving the underlying data format that's used on the wire with minimal transformation, and that format was adopted many years ago in an XML-centric world.

Another possibility: As can be seen, here, there are also multiple candidates for keys, which could use a nested dictionary structure:

```
{ 
  "image": { 
    "ami-1a2b3c4d": { 
        "webserver: "", 
        "stack": "production",
        ...
    }
  }
}
```

This structure does not lend itself to response pagination.  Many API actions return a limited result set and a continuation token.

This "improved" nested structure is also arguably harder to scan for all tags where "key" equals "stack" because you have to traverse up and down the tree.

---

¹ XML... there are exceptions, and largely undocumented is the fact that many XML service APIs secretly support JSON and some of them even support sending a request in XML and receiving a response in JSON by signaling your intentions using HTTP request headers... but in the case of JSON interactions on the wire, there's this same evidence that they appear to be transforming XML into JSON on the service side, preserving the structure, or otherwise using the same native structure for both formats, which would make sense in the interesting of making the service interactions identical regardless of the serialization.

Comment: "with the service use XML¹, where this structure makes more sense." --- xml is expressive enough to support either `<key>val</key>` syntax or `<tag name="key">val</tag>`. Both also make sense.

Comment: @zerkms I was thinking of `<key>value</key>` which is more constraining.

Comment: Thanks, that makes a lot of sense to me, and also would explain other artefacts such as (as you say) the extra level in lambda responses

Answer (score 0):

One benefit to that approach is that you don't need to know the key in advance, so you can be more flexible/modular, allowing third party to add keys and values.

Comment: How so? Why does the alternative forbid you from "knowing the key in advance"? Are you saying the more common JSON approaches are useless? If anything, the abstraction leak suggested by the syntax in the question is way harder to use and for no real benefit, surely